# How to break sublist to make each element in the sub list a normal element in the list in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

for example I have

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],3,5,6]
```

I want to turn it into

```
[1,2,3,1,2,3,3,5,6]
```

What would the code look like in python 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate `a` items, iterate subitems if the item is list; other just append to new list:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],3,5,6]
b = []
for x in a:
    if isinstance(x, list):
        b.extend(x)
    else:
        b.append(x)
# b == [1,2,3,1,2,3,3,5,6]
```

Another approach using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (nested `for`) combined with [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],3,5,6]
>>> [y for x in a for y in (x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6]
```